# Click simulation in a unit test with Angular and Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to simulate a click in a unit test that I'm developing with Jasmine.
This is my code,

First, I click my input element and type something:

```
inputElement().click();
inputElement().value = typedValue;

tick();
fixture.detectChanges();

function inputElement(): HTMLInputElement {
    return debugElement.query(By.css('#id-parent input')).nativeElement;
}
```

The point is that after the "click", I don't see the cursor inside the input element.

Second: I click outside of that input. Actually, I click a label element to simulate that:

```
andClickOutside();

function andClickOutside(): void {
    const label: HTMLLabelElement = debugElement.query(By.css('#id-label')).nativeElement;
    label.click();

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }
```

I'm creating a test which checks that **having a specific typed value, when I click outside the element, then the typed value is removed** (input get empty).

When I start the angular application in the normal way, the component works perfectly, so I can reproduce that situation.
But for some reason, in a jasmine unit test is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the input element to "blur" in order for the typed value to be removed. Rather than trying to click outside the element, you can trigger the element to blur using [Angular's `triggerEventHandler`](https://angular.io/guide/testing#triggereventhandler).

```
const input = debugElement.query(By.css('#id-parent input'));
input.triggerEventHandler('blur', {});
fixture.detectChanges();

// input should be empty here
expect(input.nativeElement.value).toBe('');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!
I also tried with inputElement().dispatchEvent(new Event('blur')); 
and also works